# DML Queries are only valid during a specific time of the day.(Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

The DML Queries should only be valid during 7am and 2pm. How do I do this. I searched a lot but I didnt find a thing.

> Thats how far I got:

```
create trigger mytrigger
before insert or update or delete on mytable
as
begin
????
end;
```

Comment: That's just a create trigger template code you've posted there, which is not what we would call a coding effort, not even close.

Comment: I am sorry but I hadn't a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps -

```
drop table t1;

create table t1
(
a number,
b varchar2(32)
);


create or replace trigger t1
before insert on t1
for each row
declare
    e EXCEPTION;
begin
    IF TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24') NOT IN ('07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14') THEN
        Raise_Application_Error (-20001, 'Data can be inserted only between 7 AM and 2 PM');
    END IF;
end t1;
/

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1,'ABC');
```

Output -

```
Table T1 dropped.


Table T1 created.


Trigger T1 compiled


Error starting at line : 22 in command -
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1,'ABC')
Error report -
ORA-20001: Data can be inserted only between 7 AM and 2 PM
ORA-06512: at "CBSADMIN.T1", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CBSADMIN.T1'
```

Comment: It's better to move the logic into one procedure. So that when you want to change the time interval you don't need to change all triggers, the changes are done only in one procedure.